# Java Logging Problem with fatjar Dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, logging, slf4j

So a quick explanation to my setup. I have a java module that is built to be a library that's used across multiple other projects. It's to simplify development, so write once, use many places.

The library is built as a gradle fatJar. When used with another newer project that's build with gradle there are no issues. But when used in an older project that's built with maven I get errors as well as no logging from the library.

- fatJar-lib: gradle, lombok slf4j
- newer project: gradle, lombok slf4j, fatJar-lib
- older project: maven, lombok slf4j, fatJar-lib

The older project is fairly large, but here are the relevant lines from pom.xml:

```
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

There are a fair number of exclusions as those were needed in the past to resolve the pesky "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" error.

Now the issue that I'm seeing that I cannot figure out is that the logging from the fatjar-lib does not work when used with the older-project. I get this output on the first attempt to write to the log:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

However, logging works just fine in the newer-project.

I've tried using the shadowJar plugin, but had issues getting that to work at all. I've tried forcing logback in the fatjar-lib with no success. I've tried re-organizing the various logging plugins in both projects, but I'm wary of changing things too much from how they are because independently the logging works fine, it's just the combination of these two projects that's an issue.

Here build.gradle of the fatjar-lib:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.1.RELEASE'
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.fatjar-lib'
version '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // Logger
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.13.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.30'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-ext', version: '1.7.30'

    // Fast.com library
    compile group: 'it.unimi.dsi', name: 'fastutil', version: '8.3.0'

    // Lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}

//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'FatJar Lib',
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    baseName = project.name
    project.version=""
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

To be clear, all of the applications functionality works ***except*** for logging within the fatjar-lib. And it's fairly critical to have that working.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Why is your library a fat jar?

Comment: It has some dependencies of its own that I want bundled. Basically the stuff that I wanted to reduce the workload on (as in the reason for the existence of the lib) are bundled. If I don't then I would need to include those dependencies in all of the projects anyways and I'm back to square one and may as well not create this lib.

Comment: Fat jars as libraries is usually considered an anti-pattern. Maven or Gradle handle the transitive dependency resolution for you, so there is no need to bundle dependencies in a library. The users of your library automatically also get the dependencies of the library.

Comment: There's no way for them to handle these dependencies as they are external libs. They are directly included within the fatjar-lib. I would need to directly add them as external libs within the other projects manually, which is what I'm avoiding.

Comment: We have hundreds of external libs and we all handle them through Maven without ever building a fat jar.